# How to declare a type for a slice of the object having certain type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Suppose there is a complex nested object (e.g. Redux state) and it is of a certain type, its top level properties are also of certain but obviously different types. Now I would like to patch it with just a slice of the whole state and I want that slice to be typed. I tried `Partial<State>` and that seems to work... but - partially... I get hints about what the props and their types are, however typescript checker now demands that I provide full objects for state props. How can I declare them partial as well?

I tried: `const slice: Record<keyof State, Partial<State[keyof State]>>`, but that doesn't work.

```js
interface ListState {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  date: Date;
}

interface NavigationState {
  state: 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
  shouldNavigate: boolean;
}

interface State {
  list: ListState;
  navigation: NavigationState;
}

const slice = { // <-- how to type this?
  list: {
    id: 2,
    date: new Date()
    // notice that name prop is missing
  }
}

const slice2 = { // ... or this?
  navigation: {
    state: 'one'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your slice is static, i.e. you know which properties it contains in compile time, you can use the `Pick` TypeScript utility:

```js
// Example definition
interface State {
  list: ListState;
  navigation: NavigationState;
}

// If it only has one state property
const slice: Pick<State, 'list'> = {
  list: {} // Your list state
};

// If it has multiple state properties
const slice: Pick<State, 'list' | 'navigation'> = {
  list: {}, // Your list state,
  navigation: {} // Your navigation state
};
```

If though you just know that it contains only some of the properties of `State` and you don't know which ones, you can just use `Partial`:

```js
const slice: Partial<State> = {
  list: {} // Your list state
}
```

In either case you should be able to do:

```js
// If oldState is of type State
const newState: State = { ...oldState, ...slice };
```

Comment: Also scenario in general is one step more complicated than that.

Comment: @jayarjo Could you please provide more information in the question? The minimal reproducible example that gives you the error? I bet we can come up with a good solution once you do that! :)

Comment: Your examples are good, it's just that properties are empty. If you populate them with some props of their own, that will basically be my case.

Comment: AAaaaaah I see, you want basically a deep merge - provide not only partial of the root state, but also only partials of the nested objects right?